# "Not allowed to use restricted network port" (WebKitErrorDomain:103)

Tags: docker, web, browser

In my Server(CentOS 7.9) I running a docker container.

```
[root@att ~]# docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
028fe4b64697        training/webapp     "python app.py"     21 minutes ago      Up 21 minutes       0.0.0.0:6000->5000/tcp
```

this is a web page.

I can in my local macOS wget the page:

```
wget remote_ip:6000
```

and get the `index.html`, but I can not access in Browser, it report error:

```
The Safari browser cannot open the page "http://demo.com:6000/". The error is: "Not allowed to use restricted network port" (WebKitErrorDomain:103)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was just running into this problem myself. Seems browsers block certain ports in the 6000-range. Not just Safari, but also Chrome/Chromium [link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/master/net/base/port_util.cc), and Firefox as well.

```
>    6000,  // X11
>    6566,  // sane-port
>    6665,  // Alternate IRC [Apple addition]
>    6666,  // Alternate IRC [Apple addition]
>    6667,  // Standard IRC [Apple addition]
>    6668,  // Alternate IRC [Apple addition]
>    6669,  // Alternate IRC [Apple addition]
>    6697,  // IRC + TLS
```

This seems to be for security reasons (I havn't dived into this). [Mozilla](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/portbanning) has a reference to a [cross-protocol attack](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/476267). That might explain why the 6xxx ports that are blocked are also standard ports for certain applications (e.g. X11, IRC).

Solution: Either use https or another port. If on Chrome you can start chrome with explicitly allowing ports.